# Is there an Angular Multiple select equivalent in jquery?

Tags: jquery, select

I was googling for a multiple select and I found this one inside [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-multiple-select), here is the [example](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/XbHaZSiYqEzxjk6TuWyj/).

For now I am not using angular in this project, and I was wondering if is there a equivalent in Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for
[Jquery-MultiSelect](http://ioncache.github.io/Tag-Handler/)